# Preventing selection of Past Date in .NET DateTimePicker

Tags: c#-3.0, datetimepicker

Does .NET already include something which I can use to prevent selection of a past date in a DateTimePicker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
dateTimePicker.MinDate = DateTime.Today;
```